# how to force compiler compile all classes in my project?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-builder

im using Adobe® Flash® Builder™ 4.6,the problem also exist in previous versions.

for some reason ,i am using

```
cls = applicationDomain.getDefinition(name) as Class;
```

to get the object's constructor and then create the instance of my modules class.thus make compile ignore my module classes ,because they are not related from my main class.how to force else classes also compiled into my swf or swc file? i didn't find where i can adjust my compile option.

by now i use this way to solve my problem,at the very beginning of the program entry.

```
if(1+1==3){
    //never be run but do make classes merge into swf files.
    new MyModule();
}
```

i have hundreds of modules like this one,i do hope i can find a way to solve this problem permanently

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try with this

```
package
{
public class IncludeClasses
{
    import com.abc.db.Database;Database;
    import com.abc.logs.RemoteLogTarget; RemoteLogTarget;
    import com.abc.logs.LocalLogTarget; LocalLogTarget;
    import com.abc.exception.GlobalExceptionHandler; GlobalExceptionHandler;
    import com.abc.utils.NetConnectionMonitor;NetConnectionMonitor;
}
}
```

Comment: by far the best.and you can simply use com.abc.db.Database;no need to import.

Comment: oops,im wrong,import must be added.you dont have to add ; at the last.

Comment: I think we need to add Class name at last otherwise flex compiler will ignore those class when compiling so you can't use reflection API.

Comment: It's hard to believe there's no way for it to include all class definitions by default.  It scans the directories after all.  At the very least, an include file should be something that's easy to auto-generate.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the class to get it to compile in the swf.
Not the best method but

```
private var someVar:someClass;
```

Using the "new" keyword will cause the run-time to allocate memory for the object so you don't want to use that.

This whole loading modules and compiling classes has a code smell to it.
You would be better off having your classes in the modules implement an interface.

Comment: your way are better than me.

Answer (score 1):

You need at least one strict reference to your class to appear within the project. I use a static variable of type Array to stuff all of the classes I need, and never really reference that array, if I can.

```
private static var dummy:Array=[OneClass, AnotherClass, Class01, Etc];
```

Comment: This one is even better.can you set the dummy to a non-static local  variable in a function?i tried,it works for me.i don't know it would keep working,need more test.

Comment: Most likely it will indeed work in a function. Once you get a link to your class from anywhere within the project, you can reach it from everywhere.

Answer (score 0):

You can also do this by setting your compiler flag.
[About the application compiler options](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf69084-7a92.html)

See:
*include-libraries library [...]*

> Include only classes that are inheritance dependencies of classes that
>   are included with the include-classes compiler option.
>
> The default value is false.
>
> This is an advanced option. You might use this compiler option if you
>   are creating a custom RSL and want to externalize as many classes as
>   possible. For example:

```
compc -include-classes mx.collections.ListCollectionView 
-include-inheritance-dependencies-only=true 
-source-path . -output lcv2 -directory
```